# Aws STS assume role for calling API Gateway

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to call an api gateway route using StsClient assumeRole (php aws sdk 3). Everything works OK, except that I do not know how to not 'hardcode' the sts user's session ARN in the role policy.
Here is my code for the serverless:

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: my-policy-apigateway
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - execute-api:Invoke
            Resource:
              Fn::Join: [ "", [ "arn:aws:execute-api:", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, ':', { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" }, ':', { "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi" }, '/*/GET/routeName/*/*/*' ] ]
            Effect: Allow
      Roles:
        - Ref: IamRoleApiGatewayExecution
```

and the STS policy (with STS and not IAM user's ARN):

```
Resources:
  IamRoleApiGatewayExecution:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                Fn::Join: [ "", [ "arn:aws:sts::", { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" }, ':assumed-role/YYYYYYYYYYYYY/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ] ]
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

I do call the route with php aws sdk (another project):

```
        $stsClient = new StsClient([
            'region' => 'eu-west-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
        ]);
        $ARN = "arn:aws:iam::.........:role/dating-crop-dev-IamRoleApiGatewayExecution-..........";

        $sessionName = uniqid('api-gateway-access-');
        $result = $stsClient->assumeRole([
            'RoleArn' => $ARN,
            'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName,
        ]);
........
```

And as I said everything works fine, except that I don't know how to make the **XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX** dynamic, otherwise I have to update it after some hours (worst practice :) ).
Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by replacing the sts user ARN by the IAM role ARN in the role's policy. So

```
            Principal:
              AWS:
                Fn::Join: [ "", [ "arn:aws:sts::", { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" }, ':assumed-role/YYYYYYYYYYYYY/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ] ]
```

becomes:

```
            Principal:
              Service: apigateway.amazonaws.com
              AWS:
                Fn::Join: [ "", [ "arn:aws:iam::", { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" }, ':role/myRoleName' ] ]
```

and it works well.